# How can I solve the issue with using ‘window open’ on ‘content.js’ file of chrome extension is blocking on chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, window.open

```
 window.open(`${chrome.runtime.getURL("options.html")}`);
```

I opened the page with ‘window.open’, but when I open it on ‘context.js’ file, the page was blocked on chrome.

But it's running normally when i relaod the page.

How can I solve this issue?

I want to use ‘content.js’ only, not ‘background.js’

Comment: Add options.html to web_accessible_resources and reload the extension.

Comment: @wOxxOm already did it .. but blocing on chrome

source code : 
 "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": ["content.styles.css", "icon-128.png", "icon-34.png","options.html"],
      "matches": []
    }
  ]

Comment: "matches": [`"<all_urls>"`]